# Quiero aumentar la edad en React y no me suma, o sea lo que hace es agregar al lado del número un 1 por cada clic, pero no lo incrementa

Tags: reactjs

Quiero aumentar la edad en React y no me suma, o sea lo que hace es agregar al lado del número un 1 por cada clic, pero no lo incrementa
import React, { Component } from "react";

```
class PersonCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      age: props.age 
    };
  }

  increaseAge = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ age: (prevState.age + 1) }));
  };

  render() {
    const { name, lastname, hairColor } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{lastname}, {name}</h1>
        <p>age: {this.state.age}</p>
        <p>hair Color: {hairColor}</p>
        <button onClick={this.increaseAge}>Birthday Button for {name} {lastname}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PersonCard;
```

Comment: Asegúrate de que parseas `age` a number antes de operar.

Comment: Prueba con `this.state = { age: +props.age };`, el + transforma el texto a número

Comment: Sí, eso fue lo que pasó no tomé como numero this.state. Cuando le agregué en parseInt funcionó correctamente. this.state = {age: parseInt(props.age)}; Gracias por sus ayudas.